# Remove item from session based on item hash in PHP

Tags: php, cart, shopping-cart

I try to delete from the session a product based on his hash and not on his id, I have several products with the same id and the problem is when I delete a product from the cart all the others containing the same id are deleted and therefore instead of product id I want to delete them through the product hash.

Here is the function that is made for remove that i want to change instead of id to be on hash remove:

```
public function remove($id, $attributes = [])
{
    if (!isset($this->items[$id])) {
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($attributes)) {
        unset($this->items[$id]);

        $this->write();

        return true;
    }
    $hash = md5(json_encode(array_filter($attributes)));

    foreach ($this->items[$id] as $index => $item) {
        if ($item['hash'] == $hash) {
            unset($this->items[$id][$index]);

            $this->write();

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Array Session Output:

```
Array
(
    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [qty] => 1
                    [hash] => 0a3610cb23dba6f6f40f74a1a9e2680a
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                          [price] => 60
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: So what is your code `unset($this->items[$id]);` doing now? Try `unset($this->items[$id][$index]);`

Comment: i have tried but is not doing anything..